# Asynchronous method showing no progress after calling inside another method

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, async-await, mqtt

I have `node-js` `db.js` class which returns me an array of data.

```
//db.js
const mysql = require('mysql');
var subscribed = [];

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'mydb'
});
connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('DB Connected!');
});


async function getTopics(subName) {

var qry = `SELECT topic_name from table where topic_name='${subName}'`;

await connection.query(qry, (err,rows) => {
  if(err) throw err;  
  rows.forEach( (row) => {
      subscribed.push(row.topic_name);
      return subscribed;
    });
});
}
module.exports.getTopics = getTopics;
```

in my another class where I am using `mqtt` in following code -- see the comments inside

```
//sub.js
var mqtt = require('mqtt')
var Broker_URL = 'mqtt://test.mosquitto.org';
var client  = mqtt.connect(Broker_URL)
const db = require('./db');

const subName = 'iPhoneX';
var subscribed = [];

async function getTopics(){
  subscribed = await db.getTopics(subName);
}

client.on('connect', function () {
  console.log('connect') // no progress after this point. stops here
  getTopics(); // calling above function here to get topics
  subscribed.forEach(element => {
    client.subscribe(element);
    console.log(element);
  });

})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  console.log(topic, '------>', message.toString());
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't mix [error-first callbacks](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/03/understanding-error-first-callbacks-in-node-js/) and [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). They are *different* techniques to work with asynchronous flows and they don't work together.

Use one or the other, preferably the latter since it's far more readable and easy to work with.

```
async function getTopics(subName) {
  var qry = `SELECT topic_name from table where topic_name='${subName}'`

  // Convert `connection.query` to a `Promise` so we can properly
  // await it.
  const rows = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    connection.query(qry, (err, rows) => {
      if (err) return reject(err)

      resolve(rows)
    })
  })

  return rows.map(row => row.topic_name)
})
```

From then on, if a function is marked as `async` it needs to be `await`ed to have it's result available in the next line:

```
client.on('connect', async function () {
  const topics = await getTopics()

  console.log(topics)
})
```

If you plan on using `async/await` you might want to use [`mysql2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper) instead, which returns Promises. You can only use `async/await` on functions that return Promises.

Comment: Or, just use mysql2 that has promises built-in.